# Does rollup bundle node_modules into bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I am testdriving [rollupjs](https://rollupjs.org/#using-rollup-with-npm) to package a node app into a `bundle.js` and am confused.

> Does rollup support bundling a full node app (including `node_modules`), or just the js files that are part of your project?

I have a standard node project (1 [`index.js`](https://github.com/datproject/dat/blob/master/index.js), thousands of files in `node_modules`) and would like just one `bundle.js`. I tried:

*rollup.config.js*:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
entry: 'index.js',
dest: 'bundle.js',
format: 'iife',
plugins: [

    commonjs({
        // non-CommonJS modules will be ignored, but you can also
        // specifically include/exclude files
        include: 'node_modules/**',  // Default: undefined

        // if true then uses of `global` won't be dealt with by this plugin
        ignoreGlobal: false,  // Default: false

        // if false then skip sourceMap generation for CommonJS modules
        sourceMap: false,  // Default: true
    }),

    nodeResolve({
    jsnext: true,
    main: false
    })
]
};
```

Whatever I try `rollup` turns this `index.js`:

```
module.exports = require('dat-node') // 88 MB node_modules
```

with this command:

```
rollup index.js --format iife --output dist/bundle.js -c
```

to this `bundle.js` without adding anything from `node_modules`:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

module.exports = require('dat-node');

}());
```

And I have tried:

- swapping plugin sequence
- all different command line options
- different formats
- different config file settings

Now I am thinking, maybe I understand rollup incorrectly and it does not support what I want. Help much appreciated!

Comment: I am facing the same problem [How to include the node_modules when bundling a TypeScript project for Node.js in one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77598848/how-to-include-the-node-modules-when-bundling-a-typescript-project-for-node-js-i?noredirect=1#comment136802331_77598848)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import nodeResolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";

export default {
  entry      : "index.js",
  dest       : "bundle.js",
  moduleName : "myModule",
  format     : "iife",
  plugins    : [
    commonjs({
      // non-CommonJS modules will be ignored, but you can also
      // specifically include/exclude files
      include: [ "./index.js", "node_modules/**" ], // Default: undefined

      // if true then uses of `global` won't be dealt with by this plugin
      ignoreGlobal: false, // Default: false

      // if false then skip sourceMap generation for CommonJS modules
      sourceMap: false // Default: true
    }),

    nodeResolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: false
    })
  ]
};
```

The main change is that you need to include `index.js` in the `commonjs` call as well, otherwise it won't get converted to an ES6 module (which is what `nodeResolve` needs).

You also need to set `moduleName`.

**NB**: I didn't test specifically with `dat-node`, but with `lodash`.

Comment: Thanx, you rock! It is doing it's thing, only now bumping into an error with `dat-node`, namely `Error: Unexpected token` in `touch-cookie` package.

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver you can solve that issue by using `rollup-plugin-json`, but when you have, it will break again (on `aws-sign2`) :-(

Comment: Ow, and that's a blocker, seeing your emoji?

Comment: I didn't look at it _very_ closely, but it's not working with the current published version of `aws-sign2`. The issue has been fixed on Github, but it was never published for some reason.

Comment: Thx, I added json plugin, but get `Error: Could not load crypto. No such file or directory, open 'crypto'`. Probably need to look at build-ins config. Will check.

Comment: And that is fixed with `external: ['crypto']` and now I have the `aws-sign2` error..

Comment: No idea if it's going to solve your problem, but you might try with another bundler, like Webpack.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a rollup issue: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1556

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it's a Rollup issue. The problem got solved in `aws-sign2` (using [this commit](https://github.com/request/aws-sign/commit/03755f299624b43dd30c33611963727f6bb6d877)), but it was never properly published to the NPM repo for some reason.

Comment: You are correct. I just found out. Will close it again.

Comment: Why can't there be a no-config option that everyone uses since they're all basically trying to do the same thing anyway? Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and searched a lot but the answers were mostly of the old syntax. After some searching, this is what worked for me.
I am not 100% sure that this is the best way to do it.

> It would be very helpful if someone more knowledgeable on rollup would verify it

So what i found does the trick is adding the modulesOnly option to the nodeResolve plugin something like this :

```js
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      format: "cjs",
      file: "dist/index.cjs.js",
    },
    {
      format: "esm",
      file: "dist/index.esm.js",
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    commonjs(),
    nodeResolve({ modulesOnly: true }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

others didn't work for me, though i worked out a minimal solution

- `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import nodeResolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";

export default {
  plugins: [
    commonjs(), // <-- this handles some parsing of js syntax or something (necessary for `export { init } from "mathjax";`)
    nodeResolve(), // <-- this allows npm modules to be added to bundle
  ],
};
```

- `package.json`

```js
{
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
        "mathjax": "^3.2.2"
    }
}
```

- `main.js`

```js
export { init } from "mathjax";
```

- shell command

```bash
rollup main.js --file bundle.js -c
```