# Rollup bundle node_modules into app when using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollupjs

I have a Typescript application. I want to bundle the dependencies inside node_modules into the resulting bundle. Here's what I've tried so far based on these posts ([Does rollup bundle node_modules into bundle.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707711/does-rollup-bundle-node-modules-into-bundle-js), [Does rollup bundle node_modules into bundle.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707711/does-rollup-bundle-node-modules-into-bundle-js)).

Here's my rollup config and the simple file I've tried bundling:

```js
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import globals from "rollup-plugin-node-globals";
import builtins from "rollup-plugin-node-builtins";

export default {
  input: "src/test.ts",
  output: {
    dir: "dist/",
    format: "iife",
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({jsnext: true}),
    commonjs({ include: ["src/test.ts", "node_modules/**"] }),
    // I need to polyfill some node stuff
    globals(),
    builtins(),
    typescript({ noEmitOnError: false, outDir: "dist/" }),
  ],
};
```

The file:

```js
import * as obj from 'some-module'
console.log(obj)
```

How can I get dependencies in node_modules to be bundled into the final output when using rollup + typescript? I suspect the issue is that the Typescript plugin is outputting files which use `require` and rollup cannot recognize `require`.

Answer (score 2):

In `package.json`, make sure the dependencies you want to include is registered in `dependencies` property not `peerDependencies`. Rollup will bundled them in the output then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure TypeScript to output ES modules for it to work. Set module to "ESNext" in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "ESNext"
    }
}
```